# Checkbox value to word through app script issue

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i'm working on an android app where I send checkboxes values to a google sheet.
My issue is that, I got value for TRUE = 1 and value for FALSE = 3 in my cells.
I need the data in the form of when the checkbox is TRUE = Done and when it's FALSE = Undone.

Comment: If the answer @MiMi gave you was useful, you could mark it as accepted.

Comment: I'm trying the answer and still having issue, but i'm still trying

Comment: Are you working with Java or with Apps Script? Could you share a sample of your code? If you work with Java, you should check out the [AddContionalFormatRuleRequest](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-api-services-sheets/latest/com/google/api/services/sheets/v4/model/AddConditionalFormatRuleRequest.html) class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Class Range You can use:

[insertCheckboxes(checkedValue, uncheckedValue)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#insertCheckboxes(Object,Object))

If your building the data validation programmatically then use:

[requireCheckbox(checkedValue, uncheckedValue)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder) from your DataValidation Builder